# Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Flutter. I have a simple app with 3 tabs. There is a RefreshIndicator in each tab with a ListView. The rows are built in another method. 
This is the code:

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _RIKey1 = new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
    final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _RIKey2 = new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
    final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _RIKey3 = new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

    debugPrint(_RIKey1.toString());
    debugPrint(_RIKey2.toString());
    debugPrint(_RIKey3.toString());
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            bottom: new TabBar(
              tabs: [
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.view_list)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.hotel)),
                new Tab(icon: new Icon(Icons.assessment)),
              ],
            ),
            title: new Text('Data'),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new RefreshIndicator(
                key: _RIKey1,
                onRefresh: _actualizoData,
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    itemCount: linea_reservas.length * 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                      if (position.isOdd) return new Divider();
                      final index = position ~/ 2;
                      return _buildRow(index);
                    }),
              ),
              new RefreshIndicator(
                key: _RIKey2,
                onRefresh: _actualizoData,
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    itemCount: linea_inouthouse.length * 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                      if (position.isOdd) return new Divider();
                      final index = position ~/ 2;
                      return _buildRowInOutHouse(index);
                    }),
              ),
              new RefreshIndicator(
                key: _RIKey3,
                onRefresh: _actualizoData,
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    itemCount: linea_ocupacion.length * 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                      if (position.isOdd) return new Divider();
                      final index = position ~/ 2;
                      return _buildRowOcupacion(index);
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'd added the debugPrints and the output are 6 lines, instead of 3.

```
I/flutter ( 5252): [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#4d76c]
I/flutter ( 5252): [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#59b9e]
I/flutter ( 5252): [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#2c88b]
I/flutter ( 5252): [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#7bd42]
I/flutter ( 5252): [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#1c984]
I/flutter ( 5252): [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#dbe20]
```

**the app works, but after changing tabs a few times, it crashes with this error:**

```
    I/flutter ( 5252): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5252): The following assertion was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
I/flutter ( 5252): Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
I/flutter ( 5252): The key [LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#7bd42] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of
I/flutter ( 5252): those widgets were:
I/flutter ( 5252): - RepaintBoundary-[<[LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#7bd42]>](renderObject:
I/flutter ( 5252):   RenderRepaintBoundary#60a4a DETACHED)
I/flutter ( 5252): - RepaintBoundary-[<[LabeledGlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>#7bd42]>](renderObject:
I/flutter ( 5252):   RenderRepaintBoundary#c8cdb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT)
I/flutter ( 5252): A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
```

The keys are generated in the Build method, so, I don't understand why the `Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey` error

Why the key is generated again, and why it's not unique? I'm not talking of a thousand intents, the error appears after changing between tabs 4 or 5 times.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is most likely a bug of `TabBarView` where both old and new children overlap for a frame. Please fill an issue.

Comment: @RémiRousselet thanks, I did, nothing yet...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Could you create your keys "by hand" and use static/constant values? e.g. ...

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class RIKeys {
  static final riKey1 = const Key('__RIKEY1__');
  static final riKey2 = const Key('__RIKEY2__');
  static final riKey3 = const Key('__RIKEY3__');
}
```

then in ...

```
    body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new RefreshIndicator(new RefreshIndicator(
// Use the Manual Static Value instead ...
                key: RIKeys.riKey1,
                onRefresh: _actualizoData,
                child: new ListView.builder(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    itemCount: linea_reservas.length * 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                      if (position.isOdd) return new Divider();
                      final index = position ~/ 2;
                      return _buildRow(index);
                    }),
              ),
```

I have done this in a similar situation with some success ... especially with redux or other similar patterns ...

Comment: how can we access like riKey1.currentState.validate() in case of Form widget validation.

Answer (score 17):

I wanted to create a List of Form Key.

just Change `GlobalKey` with `GlobalObjectKey`

like below.

```
final List<GlobalObjectKey<FormState>> formKeyList = List.generate(10, (index) => GlobalObjectKey<FormState>(index));
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who need to continue with GlobalKey:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class JosKeys {
  static final josKeys1 = GlobalKey();
  static final josKeys2 = GlobalKey();
}
```

Using as follows:

```
[
    CoachTutorialModel(
      ids: "post",
      globalKeys: JosKeys.josKeys1,
      icons: Icon(
        Icons.message,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 90,
      ),
      ...
    ),

   CoachTutorialModel(
      ids: "post2",
      globalKeys: JosKeys.josKeys2,
      icons: Icon(
        Icons.message,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 90,
      ),
      ...
    ),
]
```

Comment: type 'LabeledGlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>' is not a subtype of type 'GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>'

Comment: I don't know your case exactly, but try: static final josKeys1 = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was adding a key to a widget inside a method that was called in multiple places, the code was not mine so it took a while to debug, just gonna leave this here maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in my flutter project due to Circular dependency.
Please check if **Widget A** imported **Widget B**, and **Widget B** imported **Windget A**

Answer (score 0):

I was using a custom widget that wrapped a Container widget. I needed to pass the **key** from the custom widget to the container, and I was using a parameter **key** in the wrapper constructor. Ran into the same issue. My fix was to avoid using the word **key** in the wrapper constructor, changed it to **refKey** and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `riverpod` and `gorouter`, my navigator key was something like this:

```
final navKeyProv = Provider.autoDispose(
  (_) => GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
);
```

removing auto dispose from the provider fixed it for me:

```
final navKeyProv = Provider(
  (_) => GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Same as @babernethy above, you can have

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class JosKeys {
  static final josKeys1 = const Key('__JosKey1__');
  static final josKeys2 = const Key('__JosKey2__');
}
```

then do this on one of your Global Keys, make sure to have a different `JosKeys.josKeys{number}` for each global key

```
GlobalKey _globalKey = JosKeys.josKeys1;
```

Comment: I'm getting `type 'ValueKey<String>' is not a subtype of type 'GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>'` when doing `GlobalKey _globalKey = JosKeys.josKeys1;` Any ideas?

Comment: This is going to throw an error.