# How to use two global keys for two widgets sharing the same state class

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I am trying to create my own custom segment in flutter. That segment has two buttons, one for teachers and other for students. What I am trying to do, it's encapsulate the buttons in one Stateful Widget to handle the setState of both buttons, because I want the buttons to be an AnimatedContainer and if I rebuild the childrens (the buttons) from the parent the transition doesn't works.

Note that the buttons are Stack positioned and I reorder the content to get the tapped button over the other (that will has effect when I set more width in the tapped button, now this is not created yet).

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import '../../app_localizations.dart';
import '../../styles.dart';

GlobalKey<_ButtonState> teachersButtonKey = GlobalKey();
GlobalKey<_ButtonState> studentsButtonKey = GlobalKey();
String _globalTappedButtonId = 'teachersButton';

class FiltersAppBarSegment extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FiltersAppBarSegmentState createState() => _FiltersAppBarSegmentState();
}

class _FiltersAppBarSegmentState extends State<FiltersAppBarSegment> {
  List<Widget> buildStackChildren(SegmentChangedCallBack handleSegmentChanged) {
    if (_globalTappedButtonId == 'teachersButton') {
      return <Widget>[
        Container(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: _Button(
            key: studentsButtonKey,
            id: 'studentsButton',
            label: 'seeStudents',
            rightPosition: 1,
            onSegmentChanged: handleSegmentChanged,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: _Button(
            key: teachersButtonKey,
            id: 'teachersButton',
            label: 'amTeacher',
            rightPosition: null,
            onSegmentChanged: handleSegmentChanged,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    } else {
      return <Widget>[
        Container(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: _Button(
            key: driverButtonKey,
            id: 'driverButton',
            label: 'amDriver',
            rightPosition: null,
            onSegmentChanged: handleSegmentChanged,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          child: _Button(
            key: studentsButtonKey,
            id: 'studentButton',
            label: 'amStudent',
            rightPosition: 1,
            onSegmentChanged: handleSegmentChanged,
          ),
        ),
      ];
    }
  }

  void handleSegmentChanged(String clickedButtonId) {
    teachersButtonKey.currentState._handleButtonTapped();
    studentsButtonKey.currentState._handleButtonTapped();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 42,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Stack(children: buildStackChildren(handleSegmentChanged)),
    );
  }
}

class _Button extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id;
  final String label;
  final double rightPosition;
  final void onSegmentChanged;

  _Button({
    Key key,
    this.id,
    this.label,
    this.rightPosition,
    this.onSegmentChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ButtonState createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<_Button> {
  bool _tapped;
  double _topPosition;
  double _width;
  double _height;

  double _getTopPosition() => _tapped ? 0 : 5;
  double _getHeight() => _tapped ? 42 : 32;

  Gradient _getGradient() {
    if (_tapped) {
      return Styles.darkAccentColorGradient;
    } else {
      return Styles.darkAccentColorGradientDisabled;
    }
  }

  void _handleButtonTapped() {
    setState(() {
      _globalTappedButtonId = widget.id;
      _tapped = (widget.id == _globalTappedButtonId);
      _topPosition = _getTopPosition();
      _height = _getHeight();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tapped = (widget.id == _globalTappedButtonId);
    _topPosition = _getTopPosition();
    _height = _getHeight();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: _topPosition,
      right: widget.rightPosition,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          widget.onSegmentChanged('test');
        },
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          width: _width,
          height: _height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: _getGradient(),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(widget.label),
              style: Styles.bodyWhiteText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have already found a solution to your problem by now, but this question is one of the first search results when looking at this error.

As you already know, per the [Flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) on `GlobalKey`:

> "You cannot simultaneously include two widgets in the tree with the
> same global key. Attempting to do so will assert at runtime."

You can define your own individual keys like:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class TestKeys{
  static final testKey1 = const Key('__TESTKEY1__');
  static final testKey2 = const Key('__TESTKEY2__');
  ...
}
```

And then reference them in the widget with `key: TestKeys.testKey1`

This was described in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862572/multiple-widgets-used-the-same-globalkey) so perhaps it can help someone with the need for a similar use case.

There are also a few solutions listed [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16630)

Comment: but how will you be able to get hold of the current state? Key does not have a currentState property