# Can I use same GlobalKey for two forms in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Can I use same GlobalKey in for two forms which appear in a wizard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862572/multiple-widgets-used-the-same-globalkey

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862572/multiple-widgets-used-the-same-globalkey)

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't, and here is why:
The purpose of the `GlobalKey` is to uniquely identify the form. That means it should be unique across your application. Think of it as an ID. So, in essence, you shouldn't use a single `GlobalKey` for two forms.